# Custom Advanced query Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to query data in a google spreadsheet and copy to another sheet to generate graphs from it. I need to query data when A (DATE in dd/mm/yyyy pattern) is between StartDate and EndDate.

[image]

This date is in another sheet and it would be nice to get this dates using query from column project

[image]

The current project can be a constant and when a new project starts this constant can be updated. to query data about current project. It is possible?
Any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want the output to be but if you want to show the project number in column D of your top image then try this formula in cell D2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),LOOKUP(A2:A,Projects!B:B,Projects!A:A),))`

I set up an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XJf0i9rqAswk1nrFPyTJHpvwhcTcGHuUUkTaAjOHex4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Tks brow! It can works for me but I need to lookup to date and it must be between the start and the end of the project.

Comment: If the date in column A in first print is between start and end dates in second print then put in column D in first print Project number from second print. This is what I need now. Your example helped to think much better about how to solve this problem.